# Swipe Refresh Layout

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, swiperefreshlayout

Почему не останавливается анимация и как исправить?

```
class MainActivity: ... SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

private val mSwipeRefreshLayout:SwipeRefreshLayout? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)        
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

mSwipeRefreshLayout?.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorPrimary)

    override fun onRefresh() {
        Handler().postDelayed({    
            mSwipeRefreshLayout!!.isRefreshing = false
            toast("ОК")
        }, 400)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 swipe_container.setOnRefreshListener {
            swipe_container.isRefreshing = true
            onRefresh()
        }
```

---

```
override fun onRefresh() {
    toast("Обновление")
    Handler().postDelayed({
        swipe_container.isRefreshing = false
        toast("Обновление завершено")
    }, 2000)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вызовите [метод](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html#setRefreshing(boolean)) `mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false)`, когда нужно остановить анимацию

Comment: Ваша конструкция не отличается от конструкции в моём коде.  

This inspection reports calls to Java get and set methods that can be replaced with the use of Kotlin synthetic properties.  
``mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false)``   
``mSwipeRefreshLayout!!.isRefreshing = false``